# Internal Path Length

Tags: java, c++, algorithm, binary-tree, graph-algorithm

I had a question that I needed help on:

> Write a program for computing the internal path length of an extended binary tree. Use it to investigate empirically the average number of key comparisons for searching in a randomly generated binary search tree.

EDIT:

So I've come up with a C++ class for a binary tree

```
#include <iostream>

/*Binary tree class based on the struct. Includes basic functions insert, delete, search */

struct node
{
     int data;
     node *left;
     node *right;
};

class binarytree{
public:
     binarytree();
     ~binarytree();

     void insert(int key);
     node *search(int key);
     void destroy_tree();

private:
     void destroy_tree(node *leaf);
     void insert(int key, node *leaf);
     node *search(int key, node *leaf);

     node *root;

};

binarytree::binarytree(){
     root = NULL;
 }

binarytree::~binarytree(){
     destroy_tree();
}

void binarytree::destroy_tree(node *leaf)
{
     if(leaf!=NULL)
     {
          destroy_tree(leaf->left);
          destroy_tree(leaf->right);
          delete leaf;
     }
}

void binarytree::insert(int key, node *leaf){
     if(key < leaf->data){
          if(leaf->left!=NULL)
               insert(key, leaf->left);
          else{
               leaf->left = new node;
               leaf->left->data=key;
               leaf->left->left=NULL;
               leaf->left->right=NULL;
          }
     }
     else if(key>=leaf->data){
          if(leaf->right!= NULL)
               insert(key, leaf->right);
          else{
               leaf->right = new node;
               leaf->right->data=key;
               leaf->right->left=NULL;
               leaf->right->right=NULL;
          }
     }
}

node *binarytree::search(int key, node *leaf){
     if(leaf!=NULL){
          if(key==leaf->data)
               return leaf;
          if(key<leaf->data)
               return search(key, leaf->left);
          else
               return search(key, leaf->right);
     }
     else return NULL;
}
```

My previous question was that I needed help on the implementation. Now, if my implementation of a binary tree is correct (feel free to let me know if its not), would someone be able to help me find the algorithm for computing the internal path length of an extended binary tree? I think my implementation should cover for an extended binary tree, but I'm not sure how to find the internal path length. I've looked all over the internet, but no one seems to be able to explain it or have an algorithm to find it.

Thanks again in advance for your help! I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

**Language: C/C++:**

Create a structure like:

```
int count = 0;             //treat count,count1, count2 as global variable
int count1 = 0;            // so define these outside main ()
int count2 = 0;
int count3 = 0;
struct node{
int data;                  //data or value at that particular node
struct node* left;         //left pointer
struct node* right;
}Node;                     //Node is a type of node

Node node1 = (Node)((malloc) sizeof(Node))
  //to create a space in memory (if available) and 99.99% times it's available
```

Now, you can use whatever function you want.
Like if you want to find length:

```
int findLength(Node* head){

node* temp = head;              //initialize temp to head to use it further

   if(temp->left != NULL || temp->right!=NULL){
   count1 += findLength(temp->left);
   count2 += findLength(temp->right);
   //next line: if(count1>count2, make count3=count1 , else count3=count2)

   count3 = (count1>count2)? count1 : count2;  
   count += count3;                      //add count3 to previous value of count
   return count+1;
   }

   if(temp->left == NULL && temp->right == NULL){
   return 1;
   }

   else if(head == NULL)
      return 0;
   return count++;
}
```

Comment: Okay, I've created a basic binary tree class with insert, delete and search. Would you have any suggestions in leveraging this to answer the above question?

Comment: So essentially you pass the root node into the function and then the function scales down the left and right side adding to the count every time it runs into an internal node - thus the length is the number of internal nodes it finds?

Comment: This function finds the length of the tree and it's recursive. what it's doing is : go the left side first and then right side second, bring me the length of the tree beneath you and then come again. So, root will say "give me the length of the left subtree and then right subtree" and again left subtree will say "give me the length of my left subtree and then right Whichever is bigger make it my length". I know it's confusing but this is what it is.

Comment: Did you got what I explained ? Can u make this best answer :P